# Is there a canon meaning to the Jawa expression "Utinni!"?

Tags: star-wars, jawa, conlang

***"Utinni!"***

The expostulation (?) is almost campy at this point in the franchise. Is there a canon translation?

I am always reading it as "Hot damn!" or "Hey, Raul!" but would be delighted to learn of its intended meaning in-universe.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### "*Come on!*" or "*Let's go!*"

This is according to the (canon) factbook [*Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know)

[image]

---

In Legends canon, the word is described thusly.

> **MEETING JAWAS**
>
> For most travelers, especially those alone in the
> desert wilderness, the first sound you are likely to
> hear in a Jawa encounter is "*Utinni!*" which is **a
> battle cry of sorts, a triumphal call to all other Jawas
> nearby that prey has been located. The cry also is
> used as a great exclamation, proclaiming great wonder or excitement by whatever impresses them.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Galactic Phrase Book & Travel Guide](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Phrase_Book_%26_Travel_Guide_(real-life_book))</sup></sub>

Comment: +1 It appears that "Hot damn!" is not far off the mark. :D